# Load different font for different languages in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, lang

How do i utilize SCSS feature to load different font based on different language by using &:lang() in css? 
I am planning to use it this way at top scss file chain. Do you think this is correct?

```
//Default font-family it's not Japan language
    @font-face {
        font-family: "xxx";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url('xxx.eot');
        src: local(xxx), 
        url("xxx.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("xxx.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("xxx.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("xxx.otf") format("opentype"), 
        url("xxx.svg#xxx") format("svg");
    }

//If Japanese then
html:lang(ja) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Meiryo";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url('Meiryo.eot');
        src: local(Meiryo), 
        url("Meiryo.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("Meiryo.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("Meiryo.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("Meiryo.otf") format("opentype"), 
        url("Meiryo.svg#Meiryo") format("svg");
    }
}
```

EDIT: the above code prints out like this without any error. This should have been a bug from scss

```
@font-face {
    html:lang(jp) {
        font-family: "Meiryo";
        ....
    }
}
```

EDIT: it looks like unicode range is the solution. I'd love to know If you have any better solution. Thanks
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range

Comment: Can you show any attempt? Haven't worked with :lang(), yet, but looks pretty straightforward: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en

Comment: AFAIK `@font-face` property won't work this way, but you may include all your fonts and choose which one is used everywhere you specify `font-family`. Modern browsers will not load font if it's not used on page

Comment: I was hoping to have better way to handle different fonts using IF statement with variables. The above method works but it also download xxx default font for japan site which is unnecessary. However, xxx font is used in many other languages.

Comment: You could get the preferred language from the browser and select a specific css/scss file. Could you tell me which language you use? (PHP, JS, ...)

Comment: I use php. I don't think JS is the solution tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//If Japanese then
@font-face {
   .......
   unicode-range: 3000-303f;
}
```

The unicode-range CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters to be used from a font defined by `@font-face` and made available for use on the current page. If the page doesn't use any character in this range, the font is not downloaded; if it uses at least one, the whole font is downloaded.